# How do I display html tag in texts from Database

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to save the data in `DB` through the user. User can add `html` markup so some data will be like `<em>texts</em>` and sometimes `<br>` tag is added.

I run into a problem when I extract the data out of the `DB` and display it to the user, I got a blank field for `<br>` tag instead of showing `'<br>'`. Is there a way to display `<br>` tag as a text in my web browser when the user get data from the `DB`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `htmlspecialchars()` for escaping user's data output.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in `<pre>` tags.

The HTML `<pre>` Element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre